# EE3 Email for member account activation: how to modify

Tags: email, activation

Trying to modify text on the member account activation email on EE3. But it does not accept modification.

I modify `/system/ee/legacy/language/english/email_data.php`. Whatever I change there I always get the same old/standard text like:

> "Thank you for your new member registration."

But that sentence was changed in email_data.php. I use **Smart Member Pro**. Does that on interfere.

I am confused. What should I do different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am developer of Smart members PRO.

There is maximum 2 emails trigger when new member registers with EE.

> 1) User – Account activation instructions
>
> 2) User – Account validation notification

1) User – Account activation instructions:

This is an instruction email and will trigger only if you make users to self activate there account via email. You can change template of this email from backend: `Developer > Template Manager > Email > User – Account activation instructions`

[image]

2) User – Account validation notification:

You can change email template of new registrations from backend panel `Developer > Add-On Manager > Smart Members Pro` Settings.

Let me know if you have any queries for the same.

[image]

Comment: Yes Mufi, this part works. That's after we have activated our account. But before that we get the mentioned email with a link to activate the account. And this email I want to change bits of the text, which doesn't work..

Comment: BTW, would be great that activation email could be layouted in your excellent program ;-)

Comment: I will definitely think about it. Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited my answer. I hope that will help you.

Comment: Yes. thank you. I was too EE2 oriented and have overseen EE3 new template stuff. Happy now.